# Shared library on Linux does not contain reference to one of its dependencies

Tags: linux, gcc, dll, shared-libraries

(This question concerns the Java JNI, but I don't believe the problem actually lies with the JNI or Java)

I am executing this command:

```
cc -shared -fpic -L. -lcpdf -I$JAVA_HOME/include I$JAVA_HOME/include/linux jcpdfwrapper.c -o libjcpdf.so
```

That is to say I am building the shared library `libjcpdf.so` which needs functions from `libcpdf.so`, so should depend upon it.

On Windows (MinGW) and MacOS, the new shared library (jcpdf) clearly links to the given one (cpdf):

```
WINDOWS:

$ ldd jcpdf.dll
    ntdll.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll (0x7ffe875f0000)
    KERNEL32.DLL => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/KERNEL32.DLL (0x7ffe86400000)
    KERNELBASE.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/KERNELBASE.dll (0x7ffe851f0000)
    msvcrt.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/msvcrt.dll (0x7ffe87120000)
    libcpdf.dll => /home/JohnWhitington/jcpdf/libcpdf.dll (0x3743f0000)
    WS2_32.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/WS2_32.dll (0x7ffe870b0000)
    RPCRT4.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/RPCRT4.dll (0x7ffe87480000)
    VERSION.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/SYSTEM32/VERSION.dll (0x7ffe7d270000)

OS X:

$ otool -L libjcpdf.dylib 
libjcpdf.dylib:
    libjcpdf.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    libcpdf.so (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1311.100.3)
```

However, on Linux, we get no reference to libcpdf.so in libjcpdf.so:

```
$ ldd libjcpdf.so
linux-vds0,30,1 => (60x00007fc40b13000)
libc.so,6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fc1fb2af000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fe1fba8f000)
```

So what happens is that, whilst, from the main Java program, `System.LoadLibrary("jcpdf")` succeeds, any attempt to use the library gives:

```
java: symbol lookup error: /home/john/jcpdf/libjcpdf.so: undefined symbol: cpdf_startup
```

The whole program works fine on MacOS and Windows.

How can I tell `cc` to make `libjcpdf.so` actually depend on `libcpdf.so`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version of `cc` (or the link editor used by it) seem to default to `-Wl,--as-neeeded`. In this case, the command line order matters. If `-lcpdf` comes first, there are no references to its symbols yet, and so no dependency is created. `-l` arguments should come last:

```sh
cc -shared -fpic -I$JAVA_HOME/include I$JAVA_HOME/include/linux jcpdfwrapper.c -o libjcpdf.so -L. -lcpdf
```